# Pandas deep dive

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm very familiar with pandas and using it on a daily basis.
Recently I made couple of projects where I needed to build things in a very efficient way and I needed to understand the fundamentals pandas is built on.
I'm looking for a book/material where I can understand pandas better in term of efficiency.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already familiar with Pandas (e.g. you can fairly quickly write up a syntax to accomplish a task XYZ, and you know of a few different approaches to accomplish most common tasks), then I would suggest the better approach is to benchmark your options yourself.

You could use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for that. You're likely to get a much better insight into things this way for one, and then you'll also be building a basis on which you can add later as you identify specific needs. No need for very fancy coding, just dump a bunch of test cases with timeit in a file. It doesn't need to take that long, and is more re-usable/adaptable than reading some thing on some test case in a benchmark that may or not actually mirror the behavior of your actual data.

From quick Google searches I did earlier, what you'll find on this topic as far as I know are very broad recommendations that you likely already know about - user proper datatypes (int are faster than floats), avoid for-loops and use vectorized notations instead, etc. Those are good advices, but based on your level of understanding of Pandas, it sounds like you're already past that level of advice.

Comment: I do test them, but for example, this week I understood that np select is exhaustive, meaning it is calculating all options for all entries, and then selecting based on a condition. This can be inefficient for large number of conditions. So that's just an example of things i want to understand better

Comment: I see - but still, as far as I know, you're unlikely to find much comprehensive advices on that. This is just pretty specific stuff, there isn't a large audience for that, so who will take the time to write that up? If you still think you can find writeups on that, perhaps seaching for specific functions you're using (e.g. like np.select() etc.) might yield some blog post of some person who did a benchmark/got insights on that specific things. Perhaps someone else will come up with something better, but I doubt it.